# Upgrading from express 3.x to express 4.x - Mongo session store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm migrating from [`express 3.x`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html) to [`express 4.x`](http://expressjs.com/)

I'm having issues finding a **mongo session store** which works with the new [`session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware.

**Previously:**

`express 3.x` had [`connect`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) as a dependency, which in turn came with bundled [`session`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) middleware.

In order to persist sessions in a mongo database, the de-facto middleware was [`connect-mongo`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo).

**New world order:**

Now with `express 4.x`, `connect` is no longer a dependency.

As such, pretty much all the previously bundled middleware has been factored out into separate middleware, such as `session` listed above.

`session` takes a `store`, but since `connect-mongo` depends on `connect`, is is not compatible with `express 4.x`.

**Question:**

I cannot find information on **which mongo session store** to use when migrating to `express 4.x`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`connect-mongo` still works in `express 4.x`, however, you now pass in `session` instead of `express`

**Express 3.x:**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express); // note parameter = express
```

**Express 4.x:**

```
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session); // note parameter = session
```

**NPM:**

<s>Unfortunately, at the time of writing, the latest version of `connect-mongo` has not been deployed to npm.</s>

**EDIT: The latest version of `connect-mongo` has been deployed to [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mongo)**

You can either download the latest version direct from [github](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)

or a workaround is to create a temporary object:

```
{
    session: session
}
```

and pass this to `mongo-connect`:

```
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({session: session});
```

Comment: I am still having issues with this. Getting this error `var Store = connect.Store || connect.session.Store;
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/vinitkumar/projects/javascript/node-twitter/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:30:47)`

Comment: @Vinit I was getting the same error msg; see the last line of the answer, it fixes that.

Comment: @Vinit, sounds like you're passing in `express` to `connect-mongo`, not `express-session`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I was doing that before, but then I changed it to your example. Still let me recheck it again. I might have missed something.

Comment: I had also cloned the latest master for connect-mongo from github, still the issue persists. To make things more clear, here is my express.js file (https://github.com/vinitkumar/node-twitter/blob/fix/twitter-profile/config/express.js)

Comment: Put line 11 before line 8. You're trying to pass `session` to `connect-mongo` before you set `session = require('express-session')` (also, I don't believe you need `connect` any more? - ie: you can probably remove line 7 too)

Comment: @Vinit - not sure if you saw my last comment? The problem is you're using `session` before you've initialised it.

Comment: Or, the fix is (as of 15 minutes ago when he published the fix to NPM) is: **switch to [connect-mongostore](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mongostore)**. Their team is picking up more momentum for [Express 4.0 support](https://github.com/diversario/connect-mongostore/pull/8).

Comment: `connect-mongo` has been published on npm.  You'll now be able to pass the session directly into the `require('connect-mongo')(session)` call.